# How does one use an instance function in Haskell when ghc complains it is not in scope, despite imports?

Tags: haskell

In *A Gentle Introduction to Haskell, Version 98*, it [is said](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/modules.html):

> Instance declarations are not explicitly named in import or export
>   lists. Every module exports all of its instance declarations and every
>   import brings all instance declarations into scope.

This seems like good sense to me. Anyhow, when I try this for [fromNumber](https://github.com/haskell-game/sdl2/blob/b33aafce0d4a10a007466871267d5abe68b20415/src/SDL/Video/Renderer.hs#L945) from the `FromNumber PixelFormat Word32` instance, I'm met with the error:

```
/home/brandon/workspace/hico/src/Hico/Game.hs:269:50: error:
    Variable not in scope:
      fromNumber :: Word32 -> SDL.Video.Renderer.PixelFormat
    |
269 |   let pixFmt :: SDL.Video.Renderer.PixelFormat = fromNumber rawPixFmt
    |
```

The type in the error message looks correct to me. My relevant imports are:

```
import qualified SDL                    as SDL 
import qualified SDL.Font
import qualified SDL.Image
import qualified SDL.Internal.Types     (Window(..))
import qualified SDL.Raw
import           SDL.Raw.Video          (getWindowPixelFormat)
import qualified SDL.Video.Renderer
```

(especially the last line with `import qualified SDL.Video.Renderer`).

Out of a sense of paranoia, and since I had already a local copy of sdl2 handy, I modified the code in SDL2's `Renderer.hs` and added the below changes, which happily compiled, but shows that is not where the problem is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
-- omitted ...
  fromNumber :: Word32 -> PixelFormat
  fromNumber n' = case n' of -- ommited ...
```

I have a feeling I'm once again doing something stupid with imports, though I'm not sure.

Comment: Exporting instances does not imply exporting function definitions or class methods. In fact the error message is saying Variable not in scope (i.e. you have not imported `fromNumber` as a function), it is not saying that it cannot find an instance. What happens if you `import SDL.Internal.Numbered` (which I believe is the module defining `fromNumber`)?

Comment: Ahhh ok, I was trying to add qualifiers in a different way, which didn't really make sense.... this makes more sense, and it works! Now I will have to test out the runtime issue i was having later, but this answers my question!

Comment: @Bakuriu mind making your comment an answer?

Comment: @luqui I think Daniel answer provides all the information. @bbarker Obviously importing a package with `Internal` in its name shouldn't be done. But I believe some other module reexports `FromNumber` publicly, so you'll have to look for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instances are global, but the class itself and its methods are not. So if you have

```
module X () where
instance Foo Bar where fooBar = undefined
```

and import `X`, then you will be able to pass `Bar`s into functions which demand their arguments be instance of `Foo` (or get `Bar`s back from things that promise to produce an instance of `Foo`) -- but will not be able to name `Foo`, `Bar`, or `fooBar` yourself unless you've imported those from elsewhere!

The fix in your case is to find a module which exports `fromNumber`, e.g. by exporting `FromNumber(..)`, and import it from there.